# How to check if v-text-field has success state ( or any rule failed )?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component holding input controls ( e.g. `v-text-field` ). This component provides some props, e.g. the field rules for the input. Whenever the input value passes every rule / enters the success state I want to call a function.

Given the following sample code

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-text-field v-model="msg"
                    :rules="[ v => v.length > 0 || 'required' ]"
                    @update:model-value="onInput"
      />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('')

function onInput(newValue) {
  if(true /* text-field has success state => do things */) {
    console.log(newValue);
  }
}
</script>
```

How can I check if this field passed every rule? I wasn't able to find an event in [the docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#events)

I think it would be slow to run each rule function again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place a `ref` on the element. And `watch` its `error` value:

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field ref="input" />
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const input = ref(null)
watch(() => input.value?.error, (val) => {
  if (val) {
    // input not valid
  } else {
    // input is now valid
  }
})
```

See it [here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Notes:

- uncomment `<pre v-text="JSON.stringify(input, null, 2)"></pre>` to see everything `<v-text-field>` has to offer.
- [watch](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) is, by default, lazy. Meaning it won't be checked when the component is mounted. If you want to make this check when the component has mounted, pass a third param to it:
  `{ immediate: true }`.

Comment: For some reason the `error` state of `input` does not change. The example unfortunately doesn't work - it never goes into the 'not valid path' of the code. Any idea on why that is?

Answer (score 3):

As you said you want to validate that on focus out event, You can do that by adding the `reference` to the input field and then validate that by using this syntax in your focus out event.

```
this.$refs.msgInput.validate()
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    msg: ''
  },
  methods: {
    validateField() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.$refs.msgInput.validate()) {
          console.log('validation passed')
        } else {
          console.log('validation failed')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-text-field
    outline
    v-model="msg"
    label="Enter your message"
    :rules="[(v) => !!v || 'required']"
    @blur="validateField"
    ref="msgInput"
  />
</div>
```

**Note :** If you have a multiple inputs in your component, Then my suggestion would be that use `v-form` and attached the reference to the form. So that you can validate all the inputs in a single go on submit.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is a very nice solution but I think checking for `input.value?.error` is even better because you don't have to validate again

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your input with `v-form` component that triggers the input event with form validation state (false/true) as parameter  :

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
       <v-form @update:model-value="onInput" >
         <v-text-field v-model="msg" :rules="[ v => v.length > 0 || 'required' ]"  />
      </v-form>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref('')

function onInput(newValue) {
  if(newValue) {
    console.log('passed ',newValue);
  }
}
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: thanks for your reply. So there is no other way? Because I'm working with the focus leave event and then I would have to sync two events

Comment: and the `v-form` only checks if the whole form is valid. It doesn't know about a specific field

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to validate the whole form then you can wrap each input element inside an individual form and validate that particular field's form when required using the form's validation method.

For example-

```
<!-- Field 1 -->
<v-form ref="form_1_ref">
  <v-text-field v-model="msg"
    :rules="[ v => v.length > 0 || 'required' ]"
    @blur="validate('form_1_ref')"
    />
</v-form>

<!-- Field 2 -->
<v-form ref="form_2_ref">
  <v-text-field v-model="msg2"
    :rules="[ v => v.length > 0 || 'required' ]"
    @blur="validate('form_2_ref')"
    />
</v-form>
```

```
methods:{
  validate(form_ref) {
    // If form is not valid then return from here
    if (!this.$refs[form_ref].validate()) {
      return false;
    } 
    // Write code here
  }
}
```